# .NET website lightweight framework

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for lightweight framework to build my custom website. Originally I'd love to get a platform that implements user registration, login, logout and probably account management at some point.
The thing is I don't want to have any "extras" there and I don't want to develop sign-up/login part again...

What options do I have? I was looking at mojoPortal, but there's a lot of restrictions and features I'll never use.

Any suggestions?

PS. 
.net 2.0/3.5

Comment: This question is likely to cause lots of (equally correct) answers and discussion and thus is not a good fit for stackoverflow.  Maybe try the chat instead of asking a question.

Comment: I'm not going to start a discussion. What I want is to get available options...

Comment: And that is something explicitly not for SO. From the FAQ: "this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, *_polling_*, or extended discussion."

Answer (score 2):

asp.net mvc out of the box has the membership provider built in that allows sign up and login.

if you also need a bit of CMS like stuff, maybe try Actya

http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2012/01/23/introducing-actya/

Comment: But I wouln't name it as `lightweight framework`

Comment: depends on your definition of lightweight I guess :)